# Why is onTap not working because of padding?

Tags: flutter, dart

I made an Onboarding Page that uses ValueNotifier to change ThemeMode.
But OnTap didn't work, so I tried to fix the problem.
I found the padding was the problem.
But why is it a problem?
Why is onTap not working because of padding?
Please tell me how I can solve this and give it some padding.

main.dart

```
import '../screens/on_board_page.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'constants.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static ValueNotifier<ThemeMode> themeNotifier =
      ValueNotifier(ThemeMode.system);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ValueListenableBuilder<ThemeMode>(
      valueListenable: themeNotifier,
      builder:
          (BuildContext context, ThemeMode currentMode, Widget? child) {
        return MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          title: 'Coding with Imran',
          theme: lightThemeData,
          darkTheme: darkThemeData,
          themeMode: currentMode,
          home: const OnBoardPage(),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

on_board_page.dart

```
import '../main.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class OnBoardPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const OnBoardPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<OnBoardPage> createState() => _OnBoardPageState();
}

class _OnBoardPageState extends State<OnBoardPage> {
  // page related
  final PageController _controller = PageController(initialPage: 0);
  int pageIndex = 0;
  String titleText = 'Start Coding with Flutter!';

  // animation properties
  double animatedPositionWaveImageLeft = 40;

  // page change function
  updatePage(int nextIndex) {
    setState(() {
      pageIndex = nextIndex;

      if (nextIndex == 0) {
        titleText = 'Follow out tips\nachieve success!';
        animatedPositionWaveImageLeft = 40;
      } else if (nextIndex == 1) {
        titleText = 'Keep your\ninvestments safe!';
        animatedPositionWaveImageLeft = -350;
      } else {
        titleText = 'Start to invest\nfor your future!';
        animatedPositionWaveImageLeft = -750;
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // context related
    final ThemeData themeData = Theme.of(context);
    final Size ds = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: themeData.scaffoldBackgroundColor,
      body: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        clipBehavior: Clip.none,
        children: [
          //top dark mode and skip button
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                top: 40,
                left: 20,
                right: 20,
              ),

/* This part is weird.
Why is onTap not working because of padding? */

              child: SizedBox(
                width: ds.width,
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        print('setState');
                        setState(() {
                          MyApp.themeNotifier.value =
                              MyApp.themeNotifier.value == ThemeMode.light
                                  ? ThemeMode.dark
                                  : ThemeMode.light;
                        });
                      },
                      icon: Icon(
                        MyApp.themeNotifier.value == ThemeMode.light
                            ? CupertinoIcons.sun_max_fill
                            : CupertinoIcons.moon,
                        color: MyApp.themeNotifier.value == ThemeMode.light
                            ? Colors.amber[600]
                            : Colors.blue,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "${MyApp.themeNotifier.value == ThemeMode.light ? "Light" : "Dark"} Mode",
                      style: themeData.textTheme.titleMedium!.copyWith(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                    const Spacer(),
                    AnimatedSwitcher(
                      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
                      child: pageIndex != 2
                          ? InkWell(
                              onTap: () {
                                debugPrint('skip');
                              },
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
                                child: Text(
                                  'Skip',
                                  style: themeData.textTheme.titleMedium!
                                      .copyWith(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            )
                          : const SizedBox(),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          //background wave image
          AnimatedPositioned(
            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
            left: animatedPositionWaveImageLeft,
            child: Image.asset(
              'images/wh.png',
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              // width: 3000,
            ),
          ),
          //vector image on center
          SizedBox(
            height: 600,
            child: PageView.custom(
              onPageChanged: (nextIndex) {
                updatePage(nextIndex);
              },
              controller: _controller,
              childrenDelegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return AnimatedPadding(
                    curve: Curves.easeInOut,
                    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
                    padding:
                        EdgeInsets.only(top: pageIndex == 1 ? 100 : 0),
                    child: Image.asset(
                      'images/v$index.png',
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                  );
                },
                childCount: 3,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          //page indicators
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: ds.height * 0.05),
              child: SizedBox(
                width: 80,
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  //dynamically genrate using a list!
                  children: List<Widget>.generate(
                    3,
                    (index) => AnimatedContainer(
                      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 600),
                      height: pageIndex == index ? 15 : 10,
                      width: pageIndex == index ? 25 : 10,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(13),
                        color: pageIndex == index
                            ? const Color(0xff0CF2B5)
                            : const Color(0xff956AE8),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          //titles
          AnimatedPositioned(
            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
            bottom: pageIndex == 1 ? ds.height / 1.3 : ds.height / 11,
            child: SizedBox(
              width: ds.width,
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: ds.width * 0.09),
                child: Wrap(
                  direction: Axis.vertical,
                  spacing: 10,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      titleText,
                      style: themeData.textTheme.headlineSmall!.copyWith(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "length hardly labor deal north pair",
                      style: themeData.textTheme.bodySmall,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                right: ds.width * 0.05,
                bottom: ds.height * 0.03,
              ),
              child: AnimatedSwitcher(
                duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
                child: pageIndex == 2
                    ? FloatingActionButton(
                        backgroundColor: const Color(0xff0CF2B5),
                        onPressed: () {
                          print('floating');
                        },
                        child: const Icon(CupertinoIcons.rocket_fill),
                      )
                    : const SizedBox(),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't tap on your button due to the order of your `Stack` children. You are rendering Widgets above your button, which makes it unclickable. To fix your issue, you should move your button to the end.

```
Stack(
  children: [
    BackgroundWaveImage(),
    ...,
    Button(),
  ]
)
```

Comment: Thank you. I understood right away what you mean. The image was covering the button.

Answer (score 1):

You are using stack so your other widget is rendering above your button that's why click is not work, for solve this issue you need to move your clickable button in stack's last position. Please look into below code.

```
import '../main.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class OnBoardPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const OnBoardPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<OnBoardPage> createState() => _OnBoardPageState();
}

class _OnBoardPageState extends State<OnBoardPage> {
  // page related
  final PageController _controller = PageController(initialPage: 0);
  int pageIndex = 0;
  String titleText = 'Start Coding with Flutter!';

  // animation properties
  double animatedPositionWaveImageLeft = 40;

  // page change function
  updatePage(int nextIndex) {
    setState(() {
      pageIndex = nextIndex;

      if (nextIndex == 0) {
        titleText = 'Follow out tips\nachieve success!';
        animatedPositionWaveImageLeft = 40;
      } else if (nextIndex == 1) {
        titleText = 'Keep your\ninvestments safe!';
        animatedPositionWaveImageLeft = -350;
      } else {
        titleText = 'Start to invest\nfor your future!';
        animatedPositionWaveImageLeft = -750;
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // context related
    final ThemeData themeData = Theme.of(context);
    final Size ds = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: themeData.scaffoldBackgroundColor,
      body: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        clipBehavior: Clip.none,
        children: [
          //top dark mode and skip button

          //background wave image
          AnimatedPositioned(
            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
            left: animatedPositionWaveImageLeft,
            child: Image.asset(
              'images/wh.png',
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              // width: 3000,
            ),
          ),
          //vector image on center
          SizedBox(
            height: 600,
            child: PageView.custom(
              onPageChanged: (nextIndex) {
                updatePage(nextIndex);
              },
              controller: _controller,
              childrenDelegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                    (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return AnimatedPadding(
                    curve: Curves.easeInOut,
                    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
                    padding:
                    EdgeInsets.only(top: pageIndex == 1 ? 100 : 0),
                    child: Image.asset(
                      'images/v$index.png',
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                  );
                },
                childCount: 3,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          //page indicators
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: ds.height * 0.05),
              child: SizedBox(
                width: 80,
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  //dynamically genrate using a list!
                  children: List<Widget>.generate(
                    3,
                        (index) => AnimatedContainer(
                      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 600),
                      height: pageIndex == index ? 15 : 10,
                      width: pageIndex == index ? 25 : 10,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(13),
                        color: pageIndex == index
                            ? const Color(0xff0CF2B5)
                            : const Color(0xff956AE8),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          //titles
          AnimatedPositioned(
            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
            bottom: pageIndex == 1 ? ds.height / 1.3 : ds.height / 11,
            child: SizedBox(
              width: ds.width,
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: ds.width * 0.09),
                child: Wrap(
                  direction: Axis.vertical,
                  spacing: 10,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      titleText,
                      style: themeData.textTheme.headlineSmall!.copyWith(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "length hardly labor deal north pair",
                      style: themeData.textTheme.bodySmall,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                right: ds.width * 0.05,
                bottom: ds.height * 0.03,
              ),
              child: AnimatedSwitcher(
                duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
                child: pageIndex == 2
                    ? FloatingActionButton(
                  backgroundColor: const Color(0xff0CF2B5),
                  onPressed: () {
                    print('floating');
                  },
                  child: const Icon(CupertinoIcons.rocket_fill),
                )
                    : const SizedBox(),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                top: 40,
                left: 20,
                right: 20,
              ),

/* This part is weird.
Why is onTap not working because of padding? */

              child: SizedBox(
                width: ds.width,
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        print('setState');
                        setState(() {
                          MyApp.themeNotifier.value =
                          MyApp.themeNotifier.value == ThemeMode.light
                              ? ThemeMode.dark
                              : ThemeMode.light;
                        });
                      },
                      icon: Icon(
                        MyApp.themeNotifier.value == ThemeMode.light
                            ? CupertinoIcons.sun_max_fill
                            : CupertinoIcons.moon,
                        color: MyApp.themeNotifier.value == ThemeMode.light
                            ? Colors.amber[600]
                            : Colors.blue,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "${MyApp.themeNotifier.value == ThemeMode.light ? "Light" : "Dark"} Mode",
                      style: themeData.textTheme.titleMedium!.copyWith(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                    const Spacer(),
                    AnimatedSwitcher(
                      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
                      child: pageIndex != 2
                          ? InkWell(
                        onTap: () {
                          debugPrint('skip');
                        },
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
                          child: Text(
                            'Skip',
                            style: themeData.textTheme.titleMedium!
                                .copyWith(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                          : const SizedBox(),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```